# Print perl FTP message

Tags: perl

I am trying to print the ftp message.I am able to get the message when the login got successful but not on when user got failed to login. I am not sure what is wrong in the code.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;
use Sys::Hostname;
my $errMsg;
my $user = "test";
my $password = "test";
my $ftphostname = "test";

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftphostname, Timeout => 600) or die "Can't open $ftphostname\n";
$ftp->login($user, $password) or die "Can't log $user: ", $ftp->message;
Printf $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
exit 0;
```

Comment: What output do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I get output 'user logged in' when I pass correct creds. I would like to see the output message when login failed using $ftp->message; I know if using 'if else' conditions I am able get the message when login failed using following changes. I want to know why its not able to print when failed using $ftp->message       if 
     ($ftp->login($user, $password))
       {
         print "\n";
       }
else 
       {
         $errMsg = 'ftp '.$ftp->message;
         goto ERROROUT; 
       }

$ftp->quit;

exit 0;

ERROROUT:
 printf $errMsg;
 exit 1;

Answer (score 0):

Adding an example of a real FTP site, I could see the following message:

```
OK. Current restricted directory is /
```

When corrupting the password, I got:

```
Can't log dlpuser@dlptest.com: Login authentication failed
```

Are you seeing something else?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::FTP;
use Sys::Hostname;
my $errMsg;
# See https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/
# There are other ftp test sites out there.
my $user = "dlpuser\@dlptest.com";
my $password = "e73jzTRTNqCN9PYAAjjn";
my $ftphostname = "ftp.dlptest.com";

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftphostname, Timeout => 6) or die "Can't open $ftphostname\n";
$ftp->login($user, $password) or die "Can't log $user: ", $ftp->message;
printf $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
exit 0;
```

Comment: Ok, I missed to post part of my problem. I am using an interface(I am kicking of a job to call the FTP perl script). When I place the code in debug mode, I am able to see the 'authentication failed' on AIX server. The interface job is placed on windows server but it is using AIX agent to call the FTP perl script. The job has output window which is able to capture details of the job. Coming to original question, I am able to see the successful message on the output pane but not when the authentication failed.

Comment: Without knowing your setup, if you see the success message but not the failure, I'd suspect it has to do with the die() call and what the layers in between do on the script returning an error code.  Why don't you try switching die to a print "ERROR:..." -- then see if you get the error messages.   Ideally, the middle layers/interface should be able to capture script error return codes and handle them properly so you know what happened.  You could look into switching die with some non-zero exit codes, then your interface should be able to report the right message based on the code.

Comment: so instead of die call, I have switched to 'if else' with print error and I am able to view the error message in job output pane.if   ($ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftphostname, Timeout => 600))
     {
      print "$ftphostname server found\n";
     }
else 
     {
     $errMsg= $ftphostname.' server not found';
     goto ERROROUT; 
     }

if 
     ($ftp->login($user, $password))
       {
         print "ftp user '$user' logged in successfully\n";
       }
else 
       {
         $errMsg = 'ftp '.$ftp->message;
         goto ERROROUT; 
       }ERROROUT:
 printf $errMsg;
 exit 1;